# Plot two conditions in one plot

Tags: r, plot, conditional-statements

i'm sorry to ask such a dumb question,  but i can't find an answer ...

So i have this table called : "linearsep" :

```
  color x  y
1  red 1  1
2  red 1  3
3  red 3  3
4  red 2  4
5 blue 4  1
6 blue 6  3
7 blue 2 -2
8 blue 6 -1
```

each line corresponds to a points (1,1 ; 1,3 etc...) , I just want to plot the ''red'' points in red , and the "blue" points in blue.

I know this is pretty dumb : but i just can't find a way to get a vector with the first four line.

I thought it was something like that:

> plot(linearsep$color~x, linearsep$color~y)

but obviously it doesn't work ...
I've tested some stuff with ggplot:

```
ggplot(data=a,
+        aes(x=x, y=y, colour=color)) + geom_point()
```

Which works, but seems like a 'hack' , how can i just get the vector i want ?
Someone could please help me ... Again sorry for such a dumb question

Comment: you're almost there! you need a layer, add this to your call `+geom_point()`

Comment: and for colors/colours read this http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_point.html

Comment: Thanks i found the geom_point() just before you have posted it :) 
and thanks again for the doc : it was just what i was looking for.

> but can you tell me how to get a vector with only the blue data ? Thanks :)

Comment: To get only the blue data: `a[a$color == "blue",]`.

Comment: ok Thanks a lot , now i feel kind of dumb , but yeah : thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the complete call

```
p <- ggplot(foo, aes(x,y)) + 
geom_point(aes(colour = color)) + 
scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue"))
```

now you can do

```
p
```

or

```
print(p)
```

By assigning the ggplot to p, you can add more layers to later
by just doing `p + ggtitle("Plot Title")` for instance. This will be easier than 
typing out everything again.

For getting only blue data or any other condition, you can subset and assign 
it to new data.frame or do it within the ggplot call

```
ggplot(subset(a, colour == "blue"), aes(.....
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R:

```
with(linearsep,plot(x,y,col=color,pch=16))
```

will give you two colors. If `linearsep$color` is a factor (which it probably is), then the colors will be red and black, because `plot(...)` uses the factor levels not the labels. You can get around this by converting the factor to character.

```
linearsep$color <- as.character(linearsep$color)
with(linearsep,plot(x,y,col=color,pch=16))
```

Now the colors will be red and blue.